# Why 'q' and 'r' cannot be use as function?

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to return the perimeter and area in `int main`, but `g++` keeps throwing error messages. Please help in explanation of error. Thanks.

## Source:

```
  1 // This program takes in two values and returns the perimeter and the area of the values taken.
  2 
  3 #include<iostream>
  4 using namespace std;
  5 
  6 double perimeter (double a, double b);
  7 double area (double a, double b);
  8 
  9 int main ()
 10 {
 11     // initialization
 12     double x, y, r, q;
 13 
 14     // inputs
 15     cout << "Please enter the first value (no units): " << endl;
 16     cin >> x;
 17     cout << "Please enter the second value (no units): " << endl;
 18     cin >> y;
 19 
 20     // perimeter
 21     cout << "The perimeter is: " << r << endl;
 22     r(x, y);
 23 
 24     // area
 25     cout << "The area is: " << q << endl;
 26     q(x, y);
 27     
 28     return 0;
 29 }   
 30 
 31 double perimeter (double a, double b)
 32 {
 33     2.0 * (a + b);
 34     return 0;
 35 }   
 36 
 37 double area (double a, double b)
 38 {
 39     a * b;
 40     return 0;
 41 }
```

## Output:

```
x@xLinux:~$ g++ -Wall rectangle.cpp 
rectangle.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
rectangle.cpp:22:11: error: ‘r’ cannot be used as a function
rectangle.cpp:26:11: error: ‘q’ cannot be used as a function
rectangle.cpp: In function ‘double perimeter(double, double)’:
rectangle.cpp:33:18: warning: statement has no effect
rectangle.cpp: In function ‘double area(double, double)’:
rectangle.cpp:39:10: warning: statement has no effect
```

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know that you indent for it to call the perimeter and area function, which you never even mention in the main function?

Comment: And for that matter, you're printing the result before computing it.

Comment: Also, your `perimeter()` and `area()` functions are calculating a value, discarding it, and returning `0`.

Comment: Changed lines 21, 22, 25, 26 to reflect `perimeter (x, y)` and `area (x, y)`. Then changed lines 33, 34, 39, 40 to reflect `return 2.0 * (a + b)` and `return a * b` for perimeter and area functions, respectively. Upon compilation for `x = 10` and `y = 10`, answers were `40` and `100`, respectively. Thank you all! :)

Comment: Putting line numbers in your example is a pain as it makes it hard for us to copy and paste your code. If we need to know a line number add a comment `// <--- 22: This is line 22`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have defined `q` and `r` as doubles, then you are trying to 'call' them like a function with your `()`s

**Edit**

Also, like the other answers state, depending on what you want to do - you either need to define `q` and `r` as functions (like you have done with `area` and `perimeter` or you need to call your two existing functions on `x` and `y` e.g. `area(x, y)`

Answer (score 5):

`q` and `r` are declared as variables of type `double`.

You want to use `perimeter(x,y)` and `area(x,y)` as:

```
// perimeter
cout << "The perimeter is: " << perimeter(x, y) << endl;

// area
cout << "The area is: " << area(x, y) << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have declared `q` and `r` as variables. You cannot use them as functions because they are **not functions**. For `r(x,y)` to be valid code, you would need to declare somewhere `double r(double x, double y) { ....}` and remove the `r` variable declaration.

Please read a book or something on the basics of the language.

Answer (score 2):

```
// This program takes in two values and returns the perimeter and the area of the values taken.

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

double perimeter (double a, double b);
double area (double a, double b);

int main ()
{
     // initialization
     double x, y;

     // inputs
     cout << "Please enter the first value (no units): " << endl;
     cin >> x;
     cout << "Please enter the second value (no units): " << endl;
     cin >> y;

     // perimeter
     cout << "The perimeter is: " << perimeter(x, y) << endl;

     // area
     cout << "The area is: " << area(x, y) << endl;

     return 0;
 }   

 double perimeter (double a, double b)
 {
      return 2.0 * (a + b);
 }   

 double area (double a, double b)
 {
     return a * b;
 }
```

Comment: Surely spoon-feeding isn't the answer.

Comment: @Griffin: I disagree. Explaining in words what is wrong is not nearly as clear as a properly written piece of code. This shows exactly which errors he made and how they should be corrected. The only thing missing is that the OP should read a good textbook on C++ before continuing.

Comment: In the OP's case, *any* textbook on C++ would suffice :P

Comment: @BlackJack: LOL! OK, that is probably true, but I guess a good one would be preferable.

Comment: @Griffin: Code speaks louder than words (which are imprecise in English). But I would have added comments into the code.